# React-Native fetch JSON by Tutorial Facebook return Error

Tags: android, ios, json, facebook, react-native

React-Native fetch JSON by Tutorial Facebook return Error

**Error with null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.datasource')**

How Can i do with my code

```
class ModuleRecView extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {

      return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies),
           }, function() {
             // do something with new state
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });

    }
    render() {

      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.title}, {rowData.releaseYear}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
}

export default ModuleRecView;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json it returns 404 page not found. you can try using another json link or find the data you need here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/website/src/react-native/movies.json

Answer (score 0):

Right above `componentWillMount` do:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
  this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
  };
}
```

Comment: after insert this code it's wrong with **can't find variable: ds**
How i can do with this error

Comment: `state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
  }
    componentWillMount() {
      return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies),
           }, function() {
             // do something with new state
           });
         })`

Comment: oh yea true, ill update my answer to use a constructor to define the ds.

Comment: Okay. Many Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ListView, View, Text } from 'react-native'

class ModuleRecView extends Component {
  state = {
    datasource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r2 !== r2}),
    isLoading: true
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataSource: this.state.datasource.cloneWithRows(responseJson.movies),
       }, () => {
         // do something with new state
       });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.datasource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.title}, {rowData.releaseYear}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ModuleRecView;
```

Please note that RN now has a new Component called <[FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)/> which is the same as the `<ListView/>` component but by far better.